# N-dimension one hot features representation

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, recommender-system

I was trying to understand the features representation in this paper: 
[DRN: A Deep Reinforcement Learning Framework for News
Recommendation](http://www.personal.psu.edu/~gjz5038/paper/www2018_reinforceRec/www2018_reinforceRec.pdf)

In 4.2 Feature construction, the news features is

> News features includes 417 dimension one hot features that
>   describe whether certain property appears in this piece of
>   news, including headline, provider, ranking, entity name,
>   category, topic category, and click counts in last 1 hour, 6
>   hours, 24 hours, 1 week, and 1 year respectively

I don't understand the "one hot features" here, and google around doesn't help. If there are a lot of news, how can it be only 417 dimension, or i understand it wrong

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the actual dataset is publicly available but based on the information available in the paper, there are 417 [one hot encoded features.](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f)

For e.g. There are 10 topic categories - one hot encoding makes it into 10 dimensions. Similarly, if there are 20 providers - one hot encoding them makes it into 20 dimensions.

Comment: If the number of news in the dataset is large, there will be equal number of headlines, so if it is one hot encoded, how can it be only 417 dimensions?

Comment: Agreed, without seeing the data, I cannot say much.